# shutil.copy2 can't copy files between disk drives using Python

Tags: python, shutil

i am working on copying files between two disk drives that is from D drive to E drive , but when using shutil.copy2 and shutil.move am getting error like :

**The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive:**

and this is code i used :

```
file = "D:\Ask"
dst = "E:\Ask"
shutil.copy2(file, dst)
```

Platform : Windows
Python Version : Python 3.8.5

Comment: Is one of the two drives a network drive by any chance?

Comment: The \ need escaping - either change the filename to “d:\\Ask” or “d:/Ask or r”d:\Ask” - same for the other path.

Comment: No it is not @joostblack

Comment: OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'D:/Ask//1.log' -> 'E:/Ask/1.log'  . Am getting the same error @barny

Comment: Are you using copy2 for a reason? If not, use shutil.copy() or on Windows shutil.copyfile() should be fastest way. Do you have write permission? Does the target file already exist? Is the source file closed?

Comment: write permission ? How to give write permission with shutil  .@barny

Comment: Use [Microsoft SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and record while the error occurs. Then have a look at the captured trace and find out what the problem is

Comment: so am copying entire files from D:\Ask folder to E:\Ask folder @barny

Comment: This answer may elucidate the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098618/2961550